# F# syntax highlighting for notepad++

Tags: f#, notepad++

Does anyone know if there is any syntax highlighting for F# in notepad++ available? I love using notepad++ and would like to be able to have highlighting for my F# scripts too!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I posted [this link](http://www.mattblodgett.com/2007/11/notepad-tip-syntax-highlighting-for.html) in another answer - it explains how to get syntax highlighting working  for other file types.

Basically, find the built in scheme that most closely matches your file and add your extension to the list of matches.

Now, I don't know whether F# matches any of the existing schemes or not, so you'd have to experiment.

Comment: Thanks for the link it was very helpful. I will experiment and see how it goes.

Comment: It should match OCaml, as the languages are closely related, although it might stumble over missing keywords.  Just a guess.  YMMV

Comment: Thanks Joel - and I just read up on YMMV (Im from OZ so not familiar with the acronym/phrase) quite catchy :)

Comment: By default Caml is one of the languages available in Notepad++.  YMMV

Comment: This may be slightly off-topic, but only slightly...  I saw Brian's Depth Colorizer extension for VS2010, and liked it.  http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2010/11/